# Webservice work with iisexpress but not with IIS 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I did a WebService that pass somes parameters to a local .dll. When i compile and test the Webservice thru iisexpress in Visual Studio work perfect but when i install the WebService in IIS 10.0 the Webservice not work properly. Follow you can see a image in iis express show the windows image but in iis not show the image or window. Any configuration in iis is missing?

Thanks for your help..

[image]

Comment: What's the URL you are using for IIS.  It will be usually port 80 unlike IISExpress

Comment: The URL is http://ipadress/WSVPOS.asmx and the used port is 80. Do you recommend change the port?

Comment: Explain what is "show the windows image".

Comment: Thank you Lex. "The windows image" is the a little window with the PINPAD image, that window opens when you call a method stored in a local client machine did it in delphi .dll

Answer (score -1, accepted):

iis configuration can get tricky, i would advise you to check de globalization configuration, sometimes it can have problems with the dates or de float numbers, you can add some console.log() or alerts to see where is the problem happening